# Procedure breaks/stops at Application.WorksheetFunction.Average()

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Edition Windows 10 Pro

Version 21H2
OS build    19044.1586
Excel 2007, VBA: Retail 6.5.1057 - Forms3: 12.0.6723.500

The concern:

```vb
Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                        Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(irng)
```

When the above code is used 'manually' (F5), in the module below, it works. However, when the 'timer' triggers/engages, the procedure breaks/stops dead at that line.

I've spread the code over multiple procedures in an effort to troubleshoot; didn't help my cause.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunWhat = "kcal"  ' the name of the procedure to run
Sub StartTimer()
RunWhen = TimeSerial(23, 45, 0)
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
    Schedule:=True
End Sub

Private Sub kcal()
Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date
Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("TODAY_(24hr)").Range("E40").Value

kcal2
End Sub

Sub kcal2()
Dim i As String
Dim irng As Range
i = Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Address
Set irng = Range("B2:" & i)

Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(irng)
 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Back_Up\Bak-Up_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & "_m" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

StartTimer

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set irng = Range("B2:" & i)` is an unqualified range, so it assumes `ActiveSheet` - And probably should be `Set irng = Range("B2:B" & i)` anyway.

Comment: The best I can understand your meaning is = it's broke. What I'm not understanding is, why, both if it's unqualified --and-- the fact that the code works when run manually (F5), am I getting two different out-comes? I.E. I would think if 'i' is unqualified, it would remain that way regardless if the timer ran it, or if run from F5. Please enlighten me.

Comment: @ braX, I initially misread your ...Set irng = Range("B2:B" & i)... Using that code, two things come to mind: when the original fails and I choose 'debug', then hover the mouse over the 'i', it evaluates to the $col$num (address) correctly; but will not calculate the average. If I follow your suggestion, it appears the resulting 'var' will be B2:BB118. I say/assume that because while in debug and hovering over the 'i' <-- it's populated with $B$118.. Additionally, the code works using F5. Please explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual fix to the original 'posted\broken' code is to change --

```
Set irng = Range("B2:" & i)
```

-- To --

```
 Set irng = Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("B2:" & i)
```

While\When using the erroneous line

```
Set irng = Range("B2:" & i)
```

if and when the ActiveSheet --was any other sheet than

```
Sheets("SUMMARY")
```

the project/procedure would try and apply

```
Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(irng)
```

to that ActiveSheet, and not to

```
Sheets("SUMMARY")
```

which the ActiveSheet, when not Sheets("SUMMARY"), did not have data in the specified [ irng ] that [ Average() ] could process. <-- **That is why the code failed**. By making the change to

```
Set irng = Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("B2:" & i)
```

this is specifying 'exactly' which sheet **[ irng ]** should be **[ Set ]** to. Something that

```
Set irng = Range("B2:" & i)
```

did not accomplish.

**Thank you all for your contributions.**

Answer (score 1):

### Application.OnTime

- If this shouldn't happen in the workbook containing this code, replace all occurrences of `ThisWorkbook` with the correct workbook e.g. `ActiveWorkbook`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunWhat = "kcal"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = TimeSerial(23, 45, 0)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub

Private Sub kcal()
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TODAY_(24hr)")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY")
    dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date
    dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value _
        = sws.Range("E40").Value
    kcal2
End Sub

Sub kcal2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY")
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim irng As Range: Set irng = ws.Range("B2:B" & lRow)

    ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value _
        = Application.WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(1, 6, irng)
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Back_Up\"
    If Len(Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir FolderPath
    
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=FolderPath & "Bak-Up_" _
        & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & "_m" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    StartTimer

End Sub
```

Comment: @ VBasic2008, My original code only fails at that specific line --when it's called from the timer. It runs flawless --if its run as a macro, or manually (F5).

Comment: This *flawless* could be by sheer chance. Have you tried this solution? Did it make any difference?

Comment: @ VBasic2008, The 'flawless', is not by chance. It has been behaving like this for the last three weeks. The only time the code fails, is when the 'timer' calls it. Otherwise the code works fine. I have not used your code nor the contribution from Mr. Williams; yet. I truly want/need to know --what is breaking this simple one-line code only when it's called from the 'timer'. Respectfully.

Comment: Then I would suggest you first try Tim's solution since it has fewer changes and only afterward mine. If any of it works, just remove each change one by one and you'll find out what exactly is causing this behavior. Your feedback is most welcome.

Comment: @ VBasic2008, I was hoping to learn how to troubleshoot the original one-liner that --does work from a module when run using 'F5', but will not work when called from a timer --instead of using a donated replacement. But if that's all I have to work with; so-be-it.

Comment: I've just noticed, in Tim Williams' comments, that the code is in a sheet module. What is the name of this module? Is it the module of the `SUMMARY` worksheet? Also, is the result of this operation a one-row entry in columns `A:C`? You never clarified what *breaks/stops dead* means? Is there an error? If so, please share its number and description. Is there a particular reason why you have split this into `kcal` and `kcal2`?

Comment: @ – VBasic2008, I think I may have found what 'I' broke. Please stand-by while I test and confirm. If what I discovered, in-fact is the resolve, would you still want your questions answered or, --for me to post the entire working code?

Comment: I'll settle for both. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @ VBasic2008, The comment section won't hold the full text. I'll post the resolving code  in the next 34\hours; after testing is finalized. Unless you have another way to receive the detailed text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub kcal2()
    
    Dim irng As Range
    
    With Sheets("SUMMARY")  'make sure all ranges are tied to a specific sheet
         Set irng = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
         .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                        Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(irng)
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & _
        "\Back_Up\Bak-Up_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & "_m" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

    StartTimer

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll have to study your contribution to truly understand. The fact that this code/project in in a module for this specific sheet, suggests that your recommended 'specific sheet' association is already accomplished. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Not sure how we would know your code is in a worksheet module - it's useful to mention details like that...

Comment: @ Tim Williams, I did mention it, look at the initial post --directly under the first line of code where it states --> "When the above code is used 'manually' (F5), in the module below, it works perfectly every time." I apologize if my wording wasn't clear.

Comment: FYI "module" can mean sheet module, workbook module, regular module, or even Class module.  It's just a place to put code.  Most code posted here is in a regular module, because that's where folks typically start (maybe because that's where the macro recorder puts the code it generates).

Comment: @ Tim Williams, Thank you for the FYI; I was not aware. With regard to what module I was using; honestly, I do not know.  From the editor's menu --> Insert | Module, then entered the code. To be clear -- I inserted 'Module'; not 'Class Module'. As I posted above to VBasic2008, I may have found what 'I' broke; I'll be testing it during the next 48\hours to confirm, while I also --dig into (understand) the code you fine folks have donated. Unless something fails, I'll post the resolve here in approx. 48\hours. Respectfully.